# SFML Handle collision

Tags: c++, game-development, sfml, collision

I can't seem to actually handle a collision (basically make sure that two objects can't overlap) also I'm using pixel perfect collision so using AABB won't help.

I tried so many different ways, some were better some were worse this is the last thing I tried (this method is called when there is a collision between two objects):

```
void SystemManager::HandleCollision(int index1, int index2) {
    GameObject* object1 = Objects[index1];
    GameObject* object2 = Objects[index2];

    // Calculate the collision normal (assuming objects are circles for simplicity)
    sf::Vector2f collisionNormal = object2->Position - object1->Position;
    float distance = std::sqrt(collisionNormal.x * collisionNormal.x + collisionNormal.y * collisionNormal.y);

    if (distance != 0) {
        collisionNormal /= distance; // Normalize the collision normal
    }

    // Calculate the new direction vectors after reflection
    object1->Direction = Reflect(object1->Direction, collisionNormal);
    object2->Direction = Reflect(object2->Direction, collisionNormal);
}
```

This does not work at all, but I've had some better results. A lot of people told me I should just reset the players location but I don't understand how to implement this neither do I think it will work well (maybe/probably I am wrong).

P.S. I am kind of new to programming games and also not that good at maths and English is not my first language so yeah, sorry for any grammar mistakes. If someone is willing (don't have to) help me and contact me please say so because I would love some help. Been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: The way *I* usually do pixel perfect collision detection is: 1) Check if the axis aligned bounding box (AABB) of each object overlap - if they don't, then there can't be any collision and we can move on quickly. 2) When the AABB's do overlap I calculate the overlapping rectangle for each object and then check each pixel in that rectangle for each sprite against each other until I find one pixel in both rectangles that is not transparent - that's a collision. If all corresponding pixels in both rectangles are either both transparent or one is transparent and the other is not, then no collision.

Comment: Btw; you should read up on how to post your code as a [mre] aka [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that we can actually test compile and run for ourselves. See also [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the suggestions and I will look into all of the posting cuz it is my first post on stack overflow but I think you misunderstood me cuz I meant handling the Collison not detecting it I already set up the detection but thank you for taking your time to answer

Comment: Whoops. Yes, I did misunderstand you. As for how to *handle* the collision; one commonly used option is to simply move the colliding objects back in the opposite direction of their current movement to the first point where they are no longer colliding. Another commonly used strategy is to simply move the objects back to the position they had last frame (where they were not colliding). Another option is to let the objects bounce off each other, calculate new direction vectors and then move the colliding objects along the new vectors a distance matching how much they overlap.

Comment: That's all assuming that the objects "survive" the collision - if that's not the case, then a way to handle a collision is often that one (or both) of the objects "die" and is removed (possibly after playing a "dying" animation).